# Send a link to an image in a request

Tags: javascript, post, request

I am submitting a request for a vision OCR service. Is it possible to send a request so that a link to an image is passed to data?

```
   var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('image', $('#YOUR_IMAGE_FILE')[0].files[0]);
    $.ajax({
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'https://api.api-ninjas.com/v1/imagetotext',
        data: formData,
        enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
        processData: false,
        contentType: false, 
        success: function(result) {
            console.log(result);
        },
        error: function ajaxError(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert(jqXHR.responseText);
        }
    });
```

Comment: You would need to first upload the image data to a publicly accessible location, in order to be able to send a link to it.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossanYes, I understand that. But in this example, a file from local storage is used, and I would like to send a request with a picture via a link from the Internet, for example: https://i.imgur.com/xxxx.jpg

Is it possible?

Comment: No, not without uploading the image to public storage first. If the image is already uploaded, then sure, just set the URL string as the content you append to the FormData object: `formData.append('imageUrl', 'https://i.imgur.com/xxxx.jpg');`